# Android: Selecting an Image from sdcard and displaying it in Fragment

Tags: android-layout, android-intent

I'm working with fragments (API 4.1) and I want to let the user press a button, access his/her gallery, select an image, and have that image display an imageview on the original fragment where the button appeared.  I'm using the following code:

```
public class FillBox1Frag extends Fragment {
Button addPics, placeBox;
ImageView imgView;
Bitmap b;
Uri photoUri;
LinearLayout fillBoxLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    fillBoxLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fillbox1_frag,
            container, false);
    newBin = new Bin();
    addPics = (Button) fillBoxLayout.findViewById(R.id.bPics);
    imgView = (ImageView) fillBoxLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    addPics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent picChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            picChooser.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(picChooser, 12345);
        }
    });
    return fillBoxLayout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 12345:
        if (resultCode == 12345) {
            photoUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = FillBox1Frag.this.getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver()
                    .query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
    }
}
```

I access the Gallery, but upon selection, it just returns to the original fragment and doesn't display the image.  Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fillbox"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="fillbox" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPics"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpics" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I've found plenty of answers dealing with a similar question, but nothing that has been able to help me with how to create this process using fragments.  Any ideas on how to get my selected image to appear in the ImageView?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure your onactivityresult is called ? ? ?